# Using Roman Numerals to indicate a compound

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, nomenclature, notation

I don't completely understand it's use. Here's an example I don't understand:

Shortly after discussing $\ce{[CuCl4]^2-}$, an exam paper asked a question about copper(II) chloride. I understand that copper(II) chloride could refer to $\ce{CuCl2}$, calling it copper(II) chloride, but couldn't it also refer to $\ce{[CuCl4]^2-}$? I would understand the question in reference to $\ce{CuCl2}$, but it got confusing when I realised it could equally be referring to $\ce{[CuCl4]^2-}$, especially after it just mentioned it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, those are two distinctive species with different names:

- $\ce{CuCl2}$: copper(II) chloride;
- $\ce{[CuCl4]^2−}$: tetrachloridocuprate(II).

Oxidation number denoted with the Roman numerals in parentheses refers to the element it's placed after and doesn't carry any additional information besides the fact that copper exists as $\ce{Cu^2+}$ in both compounds.

Nomenclature rules were designed that way so that a name would unambiguously define a single compound only (I'd suggest the *Red Book's Nomenclature* by IUPAC [1] as a reference).

#### References

1. IUPAC “Red Book” Nomenclature of Inorganic Chemistry, 1st ed.; Connelly, N. G., Damhus, T., Hartshorn, R. M., Hutton, A. T., Eds.; *IUPAC Recommendations; Royal Society of Chemistry: Cambridge, UK*, **2005**. ISBN 978-0-85404-438-2. ([PDF](https://old.iupac.org/publications/books/rbook/Red_Book_2005.pdf))